# How to nest an erb call in another erb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

When I run:

```rb
ERB.new("1. <%= ERB.new('2').result binding %>. 3").result binding
```

The output is:

```
2. 3
```

While the expected output is:

```
1. 2. 3
```

Seems like the nested erb is deleting everything before it in the template. Has anyone seen this before? What is the recommended way of nesting erbs? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a conflict in the namespace specifically in the `_erbout` variable which is reinitialized by the nested ERB.

This exact case of nesting ERBs is mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.2/ERB.html#method-c-new) of `ERB.new()` saying that the variable has to be renamed using `:eoutvar` attribute if you are operating in the same scope (binding).

```rb
ERB.new("1. <%= ERB.new('2', eoutvar: \"_erbout2\").result binding %>. 3").result binding
#=> "1. 2. 3"
```